# OpenGL GL_POINTS size

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, opengl

How can I make my `GL_POINT` bigger? I'm using `glPointSize`, but its working just up to some size. So if I write

```
glPointSize(100);
```

its the same size as

```
glPointSize(500);
```

How can I make it as big as I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Primitives#Point_Primitives) says:

> There is an implementation-defined range for point sizes, and the size given by either method is clamped to that range. You can query the range with GL_POINT_SIZE_RANGE​ (returns 2 floats). There is also a point granularity that you can query with GL_POINT_SIZE_GRANULARITY​; the implementation will clamp sizes to its granularity as needed.

If the size of point you want isn't in the allowable range consider using a textured quad or even a TRIANGLE_FAN to make a (nearly) circular polygon of whatever size you desire.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a view aligned quad of whatever size you want at the point location.

Comment: I know, but I need to know if it is possible to increase point size.

Comment: @JuliusPetraška: You can't increase the point size indefinitely. Each OpenGL implementation has a certain limit, which you can query. See the answer by StuGrey.